# Webpack 4 babel loader exclude not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I try setup Webpack 4.6.0 with React and I had an issue:
[image]

in a [webpack.config.js](https://pastebin.com/eYwapxQU):

```
...
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules(?!\/myuimodule)/,
    use: ['babel-loader'],
  },
...
```

and in .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/react",
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "modules": false
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"
  ]
}
```

why babel-loader not exclude myuimodule?

Answer (score 1):

Seems crazy, but try just renaming `.babelrc` to `babel.config.json`. Not sure why this works, but it has solved the issue twice for me. Can't remember where I dug up this solution the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because of your `exclude` line. Webpack tries to build your bundle. It finds somewhere down the dependency tree starting from the `entry` this line

```
import Progress from './path/to/Progress.jsx'
```

Then it tries to parse and load your file into the bundle. It finds no rules for this file, so no loaders do their work. It encounters jsx tag and cannot parse it, so it raises an error Unexpected token and reminds developer to check loader existence for this file.

And it cannot find a loader for this file because you explicitly excluded this file from being processed by loader.

Comment: Progress.jsx is in myuimodule, which I include

Comment: In `rules` declaration `exclude: /node_modules(?!\/myuimodule)/`

Comment: But literally says `exclude` instead of `include`. Try to replace it with include.

Comment: Can you give a try to exclude as function? As mentioned here https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2031#issuecomment-283517150

Comment: Or you can add include and list as array all your source directories including myuimodule.